# List has values but not showing up in browser or postman, it appears as blank entries

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have written a simple spring boot application to do CRUD operations on a in memory H2 database, I am loading couple of records into my table using data.sql file.

When I do a findAll on my entity table, I see that it is returning 2 blank entries like this - [{},{}]

I have verified that there are values in the table and I am also able to see the values when I print the list entry explicitly like list.get(0) using overridden toString method.

Please advise me if I am doing anything wrong, I am just writing a simple api which returns all records in that database table.

Thanks,
Neeraj

Comment: Please share the code that you wrote. That would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using ‘Lombok’?

Answer (score 1):

May be the problem is with the `Getter` and `Setter` method. If you are using `Lombok` library, make sure it's installed properly in your `IDE` and added in your build dependency.

Comment: I installed lombok and restarted eclipse, still facing same issue. adding my code here. thanks

Comment: it's not allowing me to attach code, please advise. thanks

Comment: I tried that, but it's showing indentation errors. Let me try again. thanks

Comment: apologies but it's not allowing me to add code, it's a very simple thing..model with lombok annotations Data, NoargsConst, AllArgs, and Entity... a repository extending JpaRepo<Model,ID> and controller doing a simple find all using autowired repo instance.

Comment: Can you add the name of `IDE` and build tool `Maven` or `Gradle`..

Comment: just for Setter and getter